# Hyperledger Fabric endorsement failing: txid exists

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm, hyperledger-chaincode

I am currently trying to successfully invoke a chaincode on an Hyperledger Fabric network using Docker Swarm, based on [this example](https://medium.com/@malliksarvepalli/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-using-docker-swarm-and-compose-f4b70c64fa7d). My network is the following:

- org1 with peer0.org1.com + 1 CA org1 + CLI org1 + orderer.example.com from ordererOrg on PC1
- org2 with peer0.org2.com + 1 CA org2 on PC2

It seems that my network is working, but once a chaincode is instantiated on a peer then invoked, the operation is not propagated. E.g I insert data into the ledger, the chaincode container logs show that they process the data, the peer container used to invoke the chaincode seems to have correctly endorsed and simulated the query too. All of this using commands manually from inside the CLI.

**peer0.org1.com container logs**

```
2019-07-09 08:52:08.753 UTC [endorser] EndorseWithPlugin -> DEBU 3784 Entering endorsement for {plugin: escc, channel: mychannel, tx: 50732326bbe19c9eb8de42fa327ee67fc2c8102337ef96cdf9ca49fb7a0b7703, chaincode: fabcar}
2019-07-09 08:52:08.753 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 3785 Sign: plaintext: 0A2040CDC0100B7F12FA1505C311EF86...455254494649434154452D2D2D2D2D0A 
2019-07-09 08:52:08.753 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 3786 Sign: digest: 5E7E6A043E851C3316B08F5CB4A05D31840D213793C55BF14EBE64213E852F84 
2019-07-09 08:52:08.756 UTC [endorser] EndorseWithPlugin -> DEBU 3787 Exiting {plugin: escc, channel: mychannel, tx: 50732326bbe19c9eb8de42fa327ee67fc2c8102337ef96cdf9ca49fb7a0b7703, chaincode: fabcar}
2019-07-09 08:52:08.756 UTC [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 3788 [mychannel][50732326] Exit
2019-07-09 08:52:08.756 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 3789 Done with transaction simulation / query execution [50732326bbe19c9eb8de42fa327ee67fc2c8102337ef96cdf9ca49fb7a0b7703]
2019-07-09 08:52:08.756 UTC [endorser] func1 -> DEBU 378a Exit: request from 10.0.0.4:34978
2019-07-09 08:52:08.756 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 378b unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=10.0.0.4:34978 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=8.895639ms
```

A (successfully executed) query on the ledger then shows that the ledger state didn't change.

However, if I use the node SDK provided in the fabcar example from the [official samples repo](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/fabcar/javascript) (invoke.js) to invoke the same chaincode operation I get an error:

**node sdk error with node invoke.js**

```
2019-07-09T09:22:03.277Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G0:1 - endorsement failed - Error: failed to execute transaction a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9: error sending: txid: a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9(mychannel) exists
Failed to submit transaction: Error: Endorsement has failed
```

**peer0.org1.com container logs after node invoke**

```
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 15480 [mychannel][a0a2570d] Entry chaincode: name:"fabcar" 
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 15481 Entry
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 15482 Exit
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 15483 [mychannel][a0a2570d] Exit chaincode: name:"fabcar"  (0ms)
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 15484 [a0a2570d] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: PUT_STATE in state ready
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 15485 [mychannel][a0a2570d] failed to invoke chaincode name:"fabcar" , error: txid: a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9(mychannel) exists
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*TransactionContexts).Create
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/transaction_contexts.go:59
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*Handler).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/handler.go:1207
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:313
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Invoke
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:302
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:239
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:147
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:146
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:247
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:500
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:169
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*Throttle).UnaryServerIntercptor
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm/throttle.go:54
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*Throttle).UnaryServerIntercptor-fm
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:224
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:91
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:30
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:39
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:171
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:982
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1208
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:686
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
error sending
failed to execute transaction a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.processChaincodeExecutionResult
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:245
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:240
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:147
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:146
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:247
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:500
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:169
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*Throttle).UnaryServerIntercptor
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm/throttle.go:54
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/comm.(*Throttle).UnaryServerIntercptor-fm
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:224
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:91
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:30
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:39
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:171
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:982
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1208
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:686
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 15486 [mychannel][a0a2570d] Exit
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 15487 Done with transaction simulation / query execution [a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9]
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [endorser] func1 -> DEBU 15488 Exit: request from 172.18.0.1:51702
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 15489 [a0a2570d] handling PUT_STATE from chaincode
2019-07-09 09:22:03.273 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 1548a unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.1:51702 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=4.573006ms
2019-07-09 09:22:03.274 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 1548b [a0a2570d] Completed PUT_STATE. Sending RESPONSE
2019-07-09 09:22:03.274 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 1548c [a0a2570d] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: PUT_STATE in state ready
2019-07-09 09:22:03.274 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 1548d [a0a2570d] handling PUT_STATE from chaincode
2019-07-09 09:22:03.274 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 1548e [a0a2570d] Completed PUT_STATE. Sending RESPONSE
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 1548f [a0a2570d] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [chaincode] Notify -> DEBU 15490 [a0a2570d] notifying Txid:a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9, channelID:mychannel
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 15491 Exit
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 15492 [mychannel][a0a2570d] Exit chaincode: name:"fabcar"  (3ms)
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] GetTxSimulationResults -> DEBU 15493 Simulation completed, getting simulation results
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 15494 Done with transaction simulation / query execution [a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9]
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 15495 [mychannel][a0a2570d] Exit
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 15496 [mychannel][a0a2570d] Entry chaincode: name:"fabcar" 
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 15497 [mychannel][a0a2570d] escc for chaincode name:"fabcar"  is escc
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [endorser] EndorseWithPlugin -> DEBU 15498 Entering endorsement for {plugin: escc, channel: mychannel, tx: a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9, chaincode: fabcar}
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 15499 Sign: plaintext: 0A20828C242C3048295EE0453AD5EA85...455254494649434154452D2D2D2D2D0A 
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [msp.identity] Sign -> DEBU 1549a Sign: digest: F3BEDFED5C78408FD01F0A41C0714245508FD2F5AEF8A34F33E7F3C61DEFF987 
2019-07-09 09:22:03.275 UTC [endorser] EndorseWithPlugin -> DEBU 1549b Exiting {plugin: escc, channel: mychannel, tx: a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9, chaincode: fabcar}
2019-07-09 09:22:03.276 UTC [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 1549c [mychannel][a0a2570d] Exit
2019-07-09 09:22:03.276 UTC [lockbasedtxmgr] Done -> DEBU 1549d Done with transaction simulation / query execution [a0a2570dd9a4ce0c696ab08263320927382c6f3db046843dca70a96b63a97da9]
2019-07-09 09:22:03.276 UTC [endorser] func1 -> DEBU 1549e Exit: request from 172.18.0.1:51702
2019-07-09 09:22:03.276 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 1549f unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.18.0.1:51702 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=6.750666ms
```

I tried some solutions found on SO such as:

- having anchor peers set for each org: was already done
- setting `CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=org1.example.com:7051` -> failed the peer containers. If I set the address to 0.0.0.0:7051 the containers starts again but the error stays the same
- restarting Docker / removing volumes / redownloading images: didn't change a thing

**Further points:**

The orderer doesn't seem to be notified, as we can see in [its logs](https://pastebin.com/VkgnEhVC).

When I use node invoke.js I sometimes get this error, which disappears when I launch the command again. Peer logs don't show an error.

**node invoke.js inconsistent error**

```
2019-07-09T14:13:21.232Z - error: [AbstractStrategy]: constructor: No event hubs for strategy
Failed to submit transaction: Error: No event hubs for strategy
```

When I query using node, I'll sometimes get the following error:

**node query.js inconsistent error**

```
2019-07-09T13:23:13.602Z - error: [SingleQueryHandler]: evaluate: message=No peers available to query. Errors: [], stack=FabricError: No peers available to query. Errors: []
at SingleQueryHandler.evaluate (/home/path_to_dir/app/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/singlequeryhandler.js:39:17)
at Transaction.evaluate (/home/path_to_dir/app/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:246:29)
at Contract.evaluateTransaction (/home/path_to_dir/app/javascript/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/contract.js:172:39)
at main (/home/path_to_dir/app/javascript/query.js:47:39)
at <anonymous>, name=FabricError
Failed to evaluate transaction: FabricError: No peers available to query. Errors: []
```

This error usually disappears when I start a query again but will pop off from time to time. When the query comes from the CLIorg1 it never happens.

Some probably useful files:
[configtx.yaml](https://pastebin.com/Vmmn9j33)

[crypto-config.yaml](https://pastebin.com/bhaNN38k)

[docker-compose-org1.yaml](https://pastebin.com/7dDyncSi)

[docker-compose-org2.yaml](https://pastebin.com/XuLjAgzs)

EDIT: added [insert.js file](https://pastebin.com/Tme2hAwy) and logs after trying to node insert.js (see comments)

Configuration information
HLF 1.4.1 ; Docker 18.09.7 ; docker-compose 1.23.2 ; node v8.16.0 ; npm 6.4.1 ; Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Apologies for the multitude of errors which makes the question broad, but I assume they are somehow all connected to an endorsement issue. If not, do not hesitate to edit / ping me to narrow it down.

Comment: Concerning the nodejs SDK, can you share your code? You may have inserted an error by mistake (I just did this morning, worth checking it, does not take much time)

Comment: Suggest you get a log of the fabric node sdk as described in this link https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-logging.html to help you investigate the problem

Comment: @david_k done, not much use I think: https://pastebin.com/9NgLguf2

Comment: @FlorianCastelain it's the same code which used to work in a non multiple machine network. Tbh I strongly doubt that node is at fault there, hence why I didn't even tag it. Added it in the body though, thanks.

Comment: Actually it confirms what I thought was going on. For some reason the node sdk is sending the proposal twice to the same peer. Therefore the peer will accept 1 and reject the other saying the txid already exists. As to why it is doing that I don't know. Would suggest you raise a Jira as it could be a bug in the node-sdk, but it might be a configuration issue. Make sure you are on the latest version of the node-sdk first though in case there are any fixes.

Comment: @david_k thanks, I actually asked on fabric-questions describing what you just said since I figured it out, but I'll reach out to nodeSDK. I cannot seem to reproduce it in the CLI yet though.

Comment: @true : did you solve your problem? I have the same issue right now. I use node SDK (1.4.5). Thanks!

Comment: @Rouliboy I think I did, but I'm not sure, I'll try to check it when I can. Didn't touch the code since August so I can't promise I'll find anything though :/ Did you try to go to the hyperledger chat ? They were super helpful when I worked with Fabric