# Hyperledger Fabric: [Java] ContractException: Failed to send transaction to the orderer

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to submit a transaction called Plant which sets some information about a crop. However, it throws a runtime error when I submit this transaction.

I've written Java chaincode and Java application code for this, and I've used the official fabric-samples/commercial-paper as a template.
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/commercial-paper

My OS is Debian GNU/Linux 10 (Buster).

Here is the command (which submits a transaction) and the corresponding output when I run it:

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.ghostpepperfarms.Plant"`:

```
Read wallet info from: ./wallet
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.helper.Config).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Use network channel: mychannel.
Use org.papernet.commercialpaper smart contract.
Submit PLANT transaction.
org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.ContractException: Failed to send transaction to the orderer
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.TransactionImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionImpl.java:145)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.TransactionImpl.submit(TransactionImpl.java:96)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.ContractImpl.submitTransaction(ContractImpl.java:50)
        at org.ghostpepperfarms.Plant.main(Plant.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The proposal responses have 3 inconsistent groups with 0 that are invalid. Expected all to be consistent and none to be invalid.
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2022)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.TransactionImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionImpl.java:139)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The proposal responses have 3 inconsistent groups with 0 that are invalid. Expected all to be consistent and none to be invalid.
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.doSendTransaction(Channel.java:5574)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendTransaction(Channel.java:5533)
        at org.hyperledger.fabric.gateway.impl.TransactionImpl.commitTransaction(TransactionImpl.java:138)
        ... 5 more
```

It says that there are two inconsistent groups among the proposal responses- I'm assuming that this means that the smart contract is non-deterministic.

But this seems impossible to me, as this transaction simply sets the values of some fields, and doesn't use anything like date or time. (I'm not sure if this helps, but I'll mention that I've initialized all the class fields, which are all of String type, with "" .)

Logspout has previously shown a couple of errors for peer0.org1.example, but I don't see them anymore

**peer0.org1.example**:

```
peer0.org1.example.com|2021-06-24 05:18:41.568 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0ed finished chaincode: cscc duration: 1ms channel=mychannel txID=36052783
peer0.org1.example.com|2021-06-24 05:18:41.568 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0ee unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.1:53514 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=2.659998ms
peer0.org1.example.com|2021-06-24 05:18:41.657 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0ef unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.1:53514 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.084295ms
peer0.org1.example.com|2021-06-24 05:18:41.745 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0f0 unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.1:53514 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.758468ms
              couchdb0|[notice] 2021-06-24T05:18:43.549103Z nonode@nohost <0.7862.0> e9b3562462 couchdb0:5984 192.168.0.9 admin GET /mychannel__lifecycle/namespaces%2Ffields%2Fpapercontract%2FSequence?attachments=true 200 ok 8
peer0.org1.example.com|2021-06-24 05:18:43.572 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 0f1 finished chaincode: papercontract duration: 0ms channel=mychannel txID=035152c5
peer0.org1.example.com|2021-06-24 05:18:43.572 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 0f2 failed to invoke chaincode papercontract, error: txid: 035152c550d3095fb04a42d9cad6c4a9a739d83a2b680bd705eb35715116b331(mychannel) exists
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*TransactionContexts).Create
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/transaction_contexts.go:45
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*Handler).Execute
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/handler.go:1163
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).execute
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:272
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Invoke
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:202
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:155
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:126
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:119
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:187
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposalSuccessfullyOrError
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:398
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:340
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer/peer.pb.go:107
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.unaryGrpcLimiter.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/grpc_limiters.go:51
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:92
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:31
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer/peer.pb.go:109
peer0.org1.example.com|google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1180
peer0.org1.example.com|google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1503
peer0.org1.example.com|google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:843
peer0.org1.example.com|runtime.goexit
peer0.org1.example.com| /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
peer0.org1.example.com|error sending
peer0.org1.example.com|failed to execute transaction 035152c550d3095fb04a42d9cad6c4a9a739d83a2b680bd705eb35715116b331
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.processChaincodeExecutionResult
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:161
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Execute
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:156
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:126
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:119
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).SimulateProposal
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:187
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposalSuccessfullyOrError
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:398
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:340
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:32
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer/peer.pb.go:107
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.unaryGrpcLimiter.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/grpc_limiters.go:51
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpclogging/server.go:92
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/grpcmetrics/interceptor.go:31
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:25
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/chain.go:34
peer0.org1.example.com|github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer/peer.pb.go:109
peer0.org1.example.com|google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1180
peer0.org1.example.com|google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:1503
peer0.org1.example.com|google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.2
peer0.org1.example.com| /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:843
peer0.org1.example.com|runtime.goexit
peer0.org1.example.com| /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374 channel=mychannel txID=035152c5
peer0.org1.example.com|2021-06-24 05:18:43.572 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> WARN 0f3 Failed to invoke chaincode channel=mychannel chaincode=papercontract error="error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 035152c550d3095fb04a42d9cad6c4a9a739d83a2b680bd705eb35715116b331: error sending: txid: 035152c550d3095fb04a42d9cad6c4a9a739d83a2b680bd705eb35715116b331(mychannel) exists"
peer0.org1.example.com|2021-06-24 05:18:43.572 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 0f4 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.1:53536 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.851699ms
```

There seems to be a similar problem in a different setup:
[Hyperledger Fabric endorsement failing: txid exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954847/hyperledger-fabric-endorsement-failing-txid-exists)

***Further Info***: As @bestbeforetoday suggested, I analyzed the proposal response payloads (using peer chaincode invoke though), after trying to execute with mvn before.

There seem to be three payloads corresponding to 3 inconsistent groups, and I found that 'splitKey' is present in only one of the payload responses, and that the order of the remaining fields is different in each payload.

It kind of looks like this after inserting new lines and tabs:

*peer chaincode invoke*

```
Error: could not assemble transaction:
ProposalResponsePayloads do not match -
proposal response: version:1 response:<status:200

payload:"{
    \"field1\":\"\",
    \"field2\":\"\",
    \"field3\":\"\",
    \"field4\":\"\",
    \"field5\":\"\"}" >
    
payload:"\n \335-\3101\315<\016\327\324\005\037\202%\360\305\177\2369T\273\334\324X\363\020\302\"f\r6\030\373\022\325\020\n\343\010\022>\n\n_lifecycle\0220\n.\n(namespaces/fields/papercontract/Sequence\022\002\010\016\022\240\010\n\rpapercontract\022\216\010\032\213\010\n\030\000SpiceList\000bhut jolokia\000\032\356\007{
    \"field1\":\"\",
    \"field2\":\"\",
    \"field4\":\"\",
    \"splitKey\":[\"bhut jolokia\"],
    \"field3\":\"\",
    \"field5\":\"\"}"}
    
\032\330\007\010\310\001\032\322\007{
    \"field1\":\"\",
    \"field3\":\"\",
    \"field4\":\"\",
    \"field2\":\"\",
    \"field5\":\"\"}"}
    
\"\022\022\rpapercontract\032\0010" endorsement:<endorser:"\n\007Org4MSP\022\252\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nDn2uHMeio475cLoKbayZo87BRDsykM1rBNl1/bI=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" signature:"0D\002 \013v\273\205\327I >1\212\007\031\233o\276\315v\233\343\345\265r7\366\321\230\355z\361\023\005e\002 `\221\250!\372v\366\247H\213m\236\230\377\246\331\236\000\240< \337\346U\230RV\2040\376\035H" >
```

Is this the cause of the inconsistency? Why does splitKey only show up in one response? And how can I force the order of the fields to be consistent?

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to obtain the proposal responses from the `ContractException` using its [`getProposalResponses()`](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/release-2.2/org/hyperledger/fabric/gateway/ContractException.html#getProposalResponses()) method. The structure of those proposal response objects loosely aligns with the protobuf messages returned from endorsing peers, defined [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos/blob/ef707fbbf8bf90dccb2808b6f1543af3068c1caa/peer/proposal_response.proto). You may be able to inspect those proposal responses to figure out how they differ.

The proposal response payloads need to be byte-for-byte identical. An example of one case that can cause unexpected mismatches is if you are using JSON formatted data, either to write to ledger keys or as return values from transaction functions. Even if the JSON content is logically identical, if the JSON parser orders or formats the content differently, the proposal responses will no longer be byte-for-byte identical. That isn't necessarily your case, but just illustrates that there are some unusual situations that can cause this kind of problem.

Your transaction ID error looks at first glance like you might be either submitting new transactions with the same transaction ID as one already committed, or resubmitting the same transaction more than once. Certainly every transaction must have a unique transaction ID. Any transactions with the same ID as a previously committed transaction will fail. The SDK should generate a transaction ID based on both the client identity and a randomly generated nonce, so transaction ID collisions should not typically happen by accident.

Comment: I've used peer chaincode invoke to get the proposal response payloads, and I wanted to check if this might show the error- do you think that the problem involves the inconsistent field ordering and 'splitKey'?

Comment: The payloads are compared byte-for-byte so if serialized JSON contains the same data but with the fields ordered differently, that will be considered as an inconsistency between proposal responses